# Does negative definiteness imply anything about ALL principal minors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Unfortunately I haven't received any response for [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061902/definiteness-of-matrix-given-definiteness-of-principal-submatrix), so I'm trying to solve it in a different way.

1. I know that iff matrix $H$ is negative definite, its ***leading*** principal minors alternate in sign (starting with < 0 for the $H_{(1,1)}$ element).
2. I know that for a negative semi-definite matrix, a similar statement (without strict inequalities) can be made about ***all*** of the principal minors -- not just the leading ones.

But does $H$ being negative definite tell us anything about *all* of its principal minors?

e.g. Does it imply that they alternate in sign, like for negative semi-definite matrices, but with strict inequalities?

Matrices aren't in my area of expertise, so apologies if this is blindingly obvious, but I haven't found it stated anywhere, as #1 and #2 above are.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $H$ is Hermitian and negative definite, then all principal minors (the submatrices) are negative definite.

Let $\tilde H$ be such a negative definite minor with size $m\times m$, then its determinant (as product of its $m$ negative eigenvalues) has sign
$$
(-1)^m.
$$